# regex for functions containing underscore in their name

Tags: javascript, regex, sublimetext2

I am using sublime text 2 and I have a project that contains java script files. I want to search in all of my java script files if there are any functions that contain underscore in their names/definition.
e.g.

```
function search_user( arg1 , arg2 )
```

or

```
function search_another_user ( arg1 , arg2 , arg_3 )
```

it doesn't matter if there is any underscore in param name

so in words regex can be

`function <spaces and tabs> <function name containing underscore> < spaces and tabs > ( <any number of args> )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm hoping you're asking this because you want to convert all of these to camelCase function names :)

- `search_user` => `searchUser`
- `search_another_user` => `searchAnotherUser`

Right? :)

---

Use this in the search field with RegExp turned on

```
function\s+\w*_\w*
```

[image]

Comment: there is a problem it will also include `function search( arg1 , arg2 )` in the search.

Comment: Oh, I understand. You only want ones that have an underscore. Making edits now.

Comment: This will also allow functions that start with a number, which can not exist.

Comment: @Broxzier I'm assuming he's scanning _valid_ code. We're not writing a JavaScript parser here, he's just looking for functions with `_` in them.

Comment: @Broxzier also, if we wanted to get that technical, we should be looking for functions like `var search_user = function() { ... }` too.

Comment: @naomik care to share to which program your screenshot belong to??

Comment: @rps this is [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) with [Flatland theme](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/flatland) and Solarized (Light) color palette.

Comment: @naomik Wow looks better than the default themes, didnt even recognize it was sublime :), thanks

Comment: @rps, agreed. Default Sublime Text looks pretty drab. Flatland theme is the bee's knees.

Comment: @naomik sorry abt this, but I am getting only the dark background [like this](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/flatland/blob/master/screenshots.png) , mind telling me how I can get the exact one(light bg) you got in the screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

```
function\s+[a-zA-Z_].*_(.*)\b\s*\(.*\)
```

This will match what you want.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: I added a graphic to help prevent against tl;dr

Comment: @naomik Damn, very nice. What did you use to create this?